# Shortcut to convert image to JPG and AirDrop shrinks image

Tags: iphone, shortcuts-app

I've made a shortcut to AirDrop images in JPG from my iPhone to my MacBook. I want to keep using HEIC normally, but somewhat regularly want to get the JPG version quickly from my phone to my laptop.

The shortcut (see screenshot) works...but the image is resized to 360x480 or something stupid. Why is it resizing? I don't want it to resize. Am I missing something somewhere? Is it a limitation of the **Convert** step?

iOS 15.1, iPhone 11

[image: Screenshot of Shortcut]

Comment: I have a very similar shortcut, that used to work, but now also produces thumbnails instead of photos (iOS 15.6)